# WordPress Timeout When Another Theme Is Activated

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been creating a Wordpress site for 2 months. I did lots and lots of changes. I am currently using the Astra theme. When I change the theme to another one, including the official ones like twentytwenty, the site just breaks down, never loads and gives 505 timeout error at the end.

When it breaks down, I change the folder name of the changed theme

from **./wp-content/themes/sometheme**

to **./wp-content/themes/sometheme.deactive**

and so, I manually deactivate the theme and then change it back to Astra from the admin panel.

What may cause this error?

Note: I have tried resetting the **.httaccess** file, change **wp-admin** and **wp-includes** folders with the original ones, **deactivate** all of the plugins and **fix the permission issues** of the folders and files via FTP. But nothing changes.

Comment: Did you watch the error.log?

Comment: There is nothing on the error log. Actually, there is not any error log file. (I have activated the debugging)